# AngularJS dynamically changes $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs, resources

I am making my first MEAN app and I have problem with the Angular. In my app I am loading resource with some places then in controller I wrote this:

```
$scope.place = $scope.places.$promise.then(function (collection) {
    collection.forEach(function (place) {
        if (place._id === $routeParams.id) {
            $scope.place = place;
            $rootScope.map.address = place.address;
            Map.initMap(place.mapCoords);
        }
    })
});
```

It loads perfect the place on which page I am. And on this page i have this:

```
.row
    .col-lg-4
        .form-group
            label Описание
            textarea.form-control(rows='5', ng-model="place.description", required)
    .col-lg-4
        .form-group
            label Сайт
            input.form-control(ng-model="place.website")
    .col-lg-4
        .form-group
            label Адрес
            input.form-control(ng-model="place.address", ng-change="getAddress(place.addres)", required)
    .col-lg-4
        .form-group
            label Снимка
            img(ng-src="{{ img_src || '/img/uploads/' + place._id + '.jpg' }}", height="100px", width="100px")
            i.fa.fa-spinner.fa-spin.fa-4x(ng-show="img_load")
            input.form-control(type="file", file-model="place.pic")
#map

.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.pull-right(ng-click="update(place)", ng-disabled="editPlaceForm.$invalid") Обнови
.btn.btn-danger.btn-lg.pull-right(ng-click="delete(place._id)") Премахни
```

The problem is when I change input value it saves in the resource without calling any function for this. Maybe that is because my resource is cached? Any solutions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to be a bit clearer with your question. It sounds to me like your describing two way binding. Angular automatically pushes changes from the view back up to the model.  https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04

Comment: Yes, you are right that the question is not clear. So how to make a controller which uses resource and update it only when the controller call for it? And if I understood correctly all change on variables, that are resource, are updated automatically, don't they? _such as the $scope.place in my controller_

Comment: After some hours searching for solution I found something very interesting. The best way to do that is just to extend the current place (_which is resource_) to the *$scope* variable.

Comment: This code: `$scope.place = place;` now is `angular.extend($scope.place, place);`. I hope this will help someone _rookie_ :D like me!